# Add specific time to timestamp

Tags: html, mysql, codeigniter, strtotime

please, prior to responding with "Duplicate Question", I did not find anything like that one here on Stackoverflow. am injecting a timestamp into my mysql database the following way:

```
    $insertData['enddate'] = strtotime($this->input->post('openDays'));
```

this returns the date, but without a time, the output is e. g. 09/17/2013 00:00h

The hour is always the same, and I need this to always be 17:00h

Searching here and on google, I found ways to add minutes or hours to the time, but I always need this to be 17:00h, it is not a variable + XX hours.

Any clue on how to get this solved?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data coming in is a date only (`09/17/2013`, no time components), you can do this just by writing it as a string:

```
$insertData['enddate'] = strtotime($this->input->post('openDays').' 17:00:00');
```

the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function is smart enough to make the translation needed.